# For relations to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive is the property true for just the single subset $A$ or $A\times A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I was going over my notes on what it means for relations to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive and I'm unclear on one thing: is it for every $x$ in a set $A$ or set $A\times A$? So my understanding of the definitions are

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is

- reflexive if $(x,x) \in R$ for every $x \in A$
- symmetric if $(y,x) \in
     R$ whenever $(x,y) \in R$ for every $(x,y) \in  A \times A$
- transitive if $(x,z) \in R$ whenever $(x,y) \in R ,(y,z) \in R$  for every
  $x,y,z \in A$

I'm unclear why is it sometimes "$... \in A$" and other times "$... \in  A \times A$"? 
Are my notes wrong?

Comment: The one for symmetry could just as well be expressed as ‘for every $x,y\in A$’. I’ve no idea why someone chose to do it differently from the one for transitivity.

Comment: Is it necessarily wrong to say 'for ever $x, y \in A \times A$'?

Comment: Yes, because $x$ and $y$ aren’t elements of $A\times A$: they’re elements of $A$. Elements of $A\times A$ are ordered pairs of elements of $A$: if $x,y\in A$, then $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times A$. If you want to talk about every ordered pair in $A\times A$, you can say ‘for every $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times A$’. If you want to talk about every two elements of $A$, you’d say ‘for every $x,y\in A$’ or, less compactly, ‘for every $x\in A$ and $y\in A$’.

Comment: Ok but it's not incorrect to say $(x,y) \in A \times A$ because the brackets show it's an ordered pair. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation is *always* a subset of a cartesian product. In the present case, $\;R\subset A\times A\;$, and then we talk of "a relation on the set $\;A\;$", but the actual meaning is the above mentioned.

Thus, if we've a relation as above, we say it is reflexive if $\;(x,x)\in R\;\;\forall\,x\in A\;$ , as we understand both entries in each ordered pair are taken from the same set $\;A\;$, and likewise for symmetric, transitive, etc.

Comment: This doesn’t really address the OP’s question.

Comment: I think it precisely does as it addresses why somethimes the cartesian product is taken and why sometimes we refer only to the set $\;A\;$ ...Do you have a better idea, @Brian?

Comment: But that’s not the OP’s point of confusion. See my comment below the question.

Comment: But I think that is the confusion of the OP: as an example I gave reflexivity, but just as well (written is there) we could have taken symmetry: $\;(x,y)\in R\iff (y,x)\in R\;,\;\;\forall\,(x,y)\in A\times A\;$ , **or** $\;(x,y)\in R\iff (y,x)\in R\;,\;\;\forall\,x,y\in A\;$ ...just the same and all is a matter of how bored one is. But perhaps the OP can tell us whether this addresses his doubt or not. I might have missed something.

Comment: @DonAntonio : I think the OP is confused because his/her definition of "symmetric" uses "$(x,y) \in A \times A$", while his/her definition of "transitive" uses "$x, y,z \in A$".  This strikes me as inconsistent.  To be consistent, one should use (i) "$(x,y) \in A \times A$" and "$(x,y,z) \in A \times A \times A$" in the definitions of symmetric and transitive, respectively, or (ii) "$x, y \in A$" and "$x, y, z \in A$" in the definitions of symmetric and transitive, respectively.  I think (ii) is less confusing than both (i) and what actually appears in the OP's definition.

Answer (score 0):

"$(x,y) \in A \times A$" means exactly the same thing as "$x,y \in A$".  In my opinion, the definition would have been less confusing if whoever wrote the definition had written  "$x,y \in A$".  Also "$x \in A$" is equivalent to "$(x,x) \in A \times A$", but it clearly would be silly to write it that way, and fortunately whoever wrote the definition to not choose to do that.  Finally, "$(x,y,z) \in A \times A \times A$" is equivalent to "$x,y,z \in A$", but the latter is less confusing.

BTW: Brian M. Scott explains this very well in his comments.  Your question is really a notational question, and has nothing to do with properties of relations.